Issues with Venue Listing Script
I wrote a script to list the venues of a city from a website. However, I encountered two issues that I don't know how to solve:

Although I wrote code to scroll, it only captures the first 15 items and doesn’t list the rest.

The script doesn't click the "Next" button to go to the next page.
place='Abu Dhabi'
#----------------------------------------------- Cvent
url="https://www-eur.cvent.com/venues/"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
driver.maximize_window()
search_box = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input#searchString')
search_box.send_keys(place)
search_box.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
time.sleep(5)
visited_links = {}
Titles = []
pages=[]

while True:
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    cventlinks = []
    link_elements = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"li.w-full a")
    for link_element in link_elements:
        cventlinks.append(link_element.get_attribute("href"))
    Title_elements = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'li.w-full h3')
    for item in Title_elements:
        Titles.append(item.text)
    with open('CventLinks.csv', 'a', newline='') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
        for title in Titles:
            if title not in visited_links:
                writer.writerow([cventlinks[Titles.index(title)]])
                visited_links[title] = 1
    next_button=driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'a[aria-label*="Next page"]')
    ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(next_button[0]).click().perform()
    time.sleep(5)
    if driver.current_url not in pages:
        pages.append(driver.current_url)
    else:
        break



Could you please guide me?

Few issues here. First thing you need to change is the time.sleep. Use selenium's explicit wait.

1. Like @chitown88 say's, you have a timing issue. This is why you fetch only about 15 url in the first page.

You can use Implicit Waits : Selenium-python Documentation
driver.implicitly_wait(10) # The driver will wait 10 second until element is find

Then check if you find an element that you're looking for before scrolling down then adding a short delay :
# Check if first page is loaded
if len(pages) < 1: # Only apply to first page for optimization purpose
    driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"h1.text-d-xs")
    
# Scroll down
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
time.sleep(1) # Adding a delay to make sure all elements are loaded


2. next-page button seem's tricky. Instead of use click(), you can fetch the url with .get_attributes("href")

# Go to the next page
next_button = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'a[aria-label*="Next page"]')
next_url = next_button[0].get_attribute("href")
driver.get(next_url)

To avoid error, you should check if you are landing on the page "We did not find any results" to stop the script :
# Check if page error
if len(Titles) == 0:
    break


3. There is an error when trying to fetch data on page 2 :

writer.writerow([cventlinks[Titles.index(title)]])
                ~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
IndexError: list index out of range

Titles have to been in the loop as cventlinks does :
while True:
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    cventlinks = []
    Titles  = []


I hope it will help you. Have a good day and best luck to your projects.
Full script :
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import csv

#----------------------------------------------- Cvent
# Initialiaze variables
visited_links = {}
pages=[]
url="https://www-eur.cvent.com/venues/"
place='Abu Dhabi'
 
# driver configuraton
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)

# Go to the search box and search for the place
search_box = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input#searchString')
search_box.send_keys(place)
search_box.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    
while True:
    # Initialize Titles list
    Titles = []
    
    # Check if the page is loaded
    if len(pages) < 1:
        driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"h1.text-d-xs")
        
    # Scroll down
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    time.sleep(1) # Adding a delay to make sure all elements are loaded
    
    cventlinks = []

    # Get all links
    link_elements = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"li.w-full a")
    
    # Get all titles
    Title_elements = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'li.w-full h3')
    
    # Save Links to cventlinks list
    for link_element in link_elements:
        cventlinks.append(link_element.get_attribute("href"))
    
    # Save Titles to list
    for item in Title_elements:
        Titles.append(item.text)
     
    # Open .csv file
    with open('CventLinks.csv', 'a', newline='') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
        
        # Go throught title
        for title in Titles:
            if title not in visited_links:
                # Save url to .csv file
                writer.writerow([cventlinks[Titles.index(title)]])
                
                # Save title to visited_links
                visited_links[title] = 1
           
    # Check if no more page to fetch
    if len(Titles) == 0:
        break     
    else:
        # Go to the next page
        next_button=driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'a[aria-label*="Page suivante"]')
        next_url = next_button[0].get_attribute("href")
        driver.get(next_url)
    

    if driver.current_url not in pages:
        pages.append(driver.current_url)
    else:
        break
    
exit()


Thank you very much for your helpful guidance. I have implemented this now. The Next button issue is resolved, but there is still the problem of retrieving the first 15 links. The site says I have 25 venues on the first page, but my output only captures the first 15 and misses ten. Moreover, there are no duplicates!

All is working on my side with the script I provided you. Are you waiting before and after scrolling down ?  Have you try to increase time.sleep for debuging ? Also, for debuging purpose you should print values to know what is happening
